# PL/SQL: ORA-01744: inappropriate INTO

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to store the item I get from the loop into the variable I created and print it out, but I faced this error

```
28/7     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
30/39    PL/SQL: ORA-01744: inappropriate INTO
```

Here are my loop and my declare:

```
v_num1              number;
v_menuid            varchar(6);
v_menuname          varchar(100);
v_stock             number;
...
FOR loop_counter in 1..v_num1
   LOOP
      SELECT *
      FROM ( SELECT a.*, rownum rnum
             FROM ( SELECT menuitemid INTO v_menuid, menuitemname INTO v_menuname, quantityinstock INTO v_stock
                    FROM menuitem m, restaurant r
                    WHERE m.restaurantid = r.restaurantid AND restaurantname = IN_ResName AND quantityinstock <= 10) a
             WHERE rownum <= loop_counter ) 
      WHERE rnum >= loop_counter;
       
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(chr(10));
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Menu ID: '||v_menuid);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Menu Name: '||v_menuname);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Quantity In Stock: '||v_stock);

   END LOOP;
```

I want to print out the result like :

```
Menu ID: M00001
Menu Name: Burger
Stock : 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Only one INTO statement per projection.
2. The INTO statement belongs in the outermost projection.

```
SELECT menuitemid , menuitemname, quantityinstock
INTO v_menuid, v_menuname, v_stock
FROM ( SELECT a.*, rownum rnum
       FROM ( SELECT menuitemid, menuitemname, quantityinstock
              FROM menuitem m, restaurant r
              WHERE m.restaurantid = r.restaurantid AND restaurantname = IN_ResName AND quantityinstock <= 10) a
       WHERE rownum <= loop_counter ) 
WHERE rnum >= loop_counter;
```